# Why does the INT Rank change, and why does it not override? I don't see it updating or any code that can change it

Tags: c, function, cs50, rank

I'm doing CS50 and I am currently at the Tideman problem. Here we have to write a function code that completes the vote function. When I do check my answers for the funtion it does work, although I don't completely understand how it does it.

I tried to debug it and see how the values change. Let me be clear it is about the vote funtion, and the part I don't understand is the INT vote. Why does it change value?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote (hierin werken)
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    printf("Rank begin snap niet %i \n", rank);

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 3)
        {
            printf("0: %i 1: %i 2: %i", ranks[0], ranks[1], ranks[2]);
        }
        {
            printf("Array rank %i \n", ranks[i]);
        }
        if (strcmp(candidates[i], name)==0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }


    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    // if (ranks[i] < candidates[i])
    //     {
    //         int preferences[i][i] = ranks[i];
    //     }

    // // TODO
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: *What* "hexadecimal value" don't you understand? Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And how come you don't understand code that you have written yourself? If you end up in such a situation, it's likely that you attempt to go beyond your current limits and knowledge, and that you should slow down and go back to repeat things you don't quite understand.

Comment: There is no code in the question as currently written that prints any hexadecimal values.  That makes it hard for us to understand what you're talking about.  In ordinary code, error messages should be printed on `stderr`, not `stdout` (using `fprintf(stderr, …)` rather than `printf(…)`).

Comment: Well, I just started programming and CS50 is an introductional course. So thats why I don't understand everything. So my main question is, in the vote function you have the INT Rank. Which doesn't get updated by the loop, yet somehow changes valeu. Why does it do so?

Comment: `INT` isn't a type in C, which is a case-sensitive language.  Do you mean `int rank`?  Unfortunately, programming requires great care and attention to lots of details.  And inside the `vote()` function, nothing ever changes `rank`, so why would you expect it to change?  There is an assignment to `ranks[rank]`, but that's an array of integers.  As long as `rank` is under control (not outside the bounds of the array), there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'll try to be more carefull. I did mean int rank.  Can you maybe explain a bit about the ranks[rank] what you mean by assignment?

Comment: `ranks[]` is an array, and `rank` is an index into that array. `ranks[rank] = i;` changes the value of index `rank` in the `ranks` array to whatever value `i` contains.

Comment: When you debugged, did you use an actual debugger? If you did, then good. And when you used the debugger to step through the `vote` function line by line, could any index be out of bounds for `ranks`?

Comment: Do you understand how, if you have `int array[10]; int j = 5; array[j] = 42;`, then after the assignment, `array[5] == 42`?  The same principles apply to `ranks[rank] = i;`.  After the assignment, the element of the array `ranks` identified by `rank` contains the value in `i` at the time of the assignment.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to show us how you invoke your program (including all arguments), the exact input you give, and the exact output you get as well as the output you expect.

Comment: Thanks for help! I used the debug50 functionality, when I debug using visual studio code I get an error. All the answers have helped me, I'll go back to visual studio code and try to get a better picture in my head.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "After the assignment, the element of the array ranks identified by rank contains the value in i at the time of the assignment." I think this is the crux of what I don't understand. Your explaination helps, but I don't fully grasp it yet. Can you maybe word it differently? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you understand the `array`, `j`, and `array[j] = 42` example?  It is isomorphic with the `ranks[rank] = i` example.  That is: `array` and `ranks` are both arrays of integers; `j` and `rank` are both indexes into the corresponding array; and `42` and `i` are the values assigned to the element of the array.  The 'at the time of the assignment' qualifier is because if `i` changes after the assignment, the value in `ranks[rank]` doesn't change.

Comment: Do you understand something like `int x; x = 10;`? Assigning to elements of an array works exactly like that, there's no difference between plain variable assignment and array element assignment.

Comment: @neuqert with array[i] you determine the location of the value as index in the list. Changing the value of that would be array[i] = someInteger

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes I do understand that. What I do not understand is that the int rank does not change. So each time the vote function loops and this code is run        
     stating ranks[rank] = i. Then what changes the int rank value? I understand i changes because of the loop.

Comment: You call the `vote` function in the loop `for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)`. The value for `rank` inside the function is the variable `j` you pass in the call `vote(j, name, ranks)`. Do you mean that the value of `rank` changes *inside* the `vote` function? Then again, please tell us the actual arguments you pass to the *program* and the actual *input* you give. Otherwise it's very hard for us to help you debug your possible problem.

Comment: I understand it finally, int rank is amount of times the vote funtion has been called. Thank you all for the helping me find the solution

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o you understand how, if you have int array[10]; int j = 5; array[j] = 42;, then after the assignment, array[5] == 42? The same principles apply to ranks[rank] = i;. After the assignment, the element of the array ranks identified by rank contains the value in i at the time of the assignment. –
Jonathan Leffler
5 hours ago

Do you understand the array, j, and array[j] = 42 example? It is isomorphic with the ranks[rank] = i example. That is: array and ranks are both arrays of integers; j and rank are both indexes into the corresponding array; and 42 and i are the values assigned to the element of the array. The 'at the time of the assignment' qualifier is because if i changes after the assignment, the value in ranks[rank] doesn't change. –
Jonathan Leffler
5 hours ago